# Excel macro to find new data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a macro to find new data by comparing two data sets (current year and prior year). I have two data sets in a file and there a few entries which are present this year but were not there in previous year. I need to write a macro to identify those claims and list them in a separate worksheet.
Prior Year : A, B, C, D, E, F
Current Year : A, Y, B, C, D, E, F. 
In this example, Y is the new entry. So I need to create a macro that will identify all such cases and give me a list of them in another sheet.

Comment: Have you written any code, tried anything yet?

Comment: Without any example or any part of code that you tried to write it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: This can be easily done with excel formulas. Why do you need a VBA for this? Unless we see some data of yours we will not be able to help you out

Comment: @GowthamShiva: I need a code because I need to do similar type of activities various times in one sheet. So I think writing a code will be useful.

Comment: @samiles: I tried recording the macro, but unfortunately it didn't worked. I am new to coding thus not able to write one myself

Comment: "I am new to coding thus not able to write one myself" - They you are on the wrong website. Google "Beginner VBA Tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

Please do the things step-by-step,

1) Prior year data is in `Sheet2` in `column A` as in image below,

[image]

2) Current year data is in `Sheet3` same as prior year,

[image]

3) Create a sheet in the name `Sheet4` where you will get the output.

4) Run the macro in `Sheet3` (guessing you know how to do it), the code is below.

```
Sub findDiff()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
j = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
k = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & j), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i)) = 0 Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & (k + 1))
        k = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

5) Output will be written to `Sheet4` as below,

[image]

Hope this helps.